# Buffer Overflow 2 picoCTF

Tags: ctf, pwntools

I would be happy if someone explain me how are the arguments of the win function passed to the win function by overwriting the stack after the return address of the current stack frame, what does actually happen behind the scenes?

I understood that we overwrite the current ebp plus 8 and the current ebp us 12 by the arguments to the function (and of course that I overwrited the return address with the address of win) but I did not get how it works.